# stackblitz -> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: stackblitz

I have created a simple `JavaScript` project in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and trying to include 
dropzone.js but getting below error message

```
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://js-gxqqqw.stackblitz.io/dropzone.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

There are lot of similar posts but I could not find anything that is relevant to stackblitz.

[Here is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gxqqqw) my stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gxqqqw

In-fact I am not able to include any other JS file using script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Not_able_to_include_any_js_file.js"></script>
```

Comment: i guess using npm dependency is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the script tag to link tag with **rel="preload"** and **as="script"** attributes should fix the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="dropzone.js" as="script" />
  </head>

  <body>
    Content of the document......
  </body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload#including_a_mime_type